# Open Excel VBA 2016 .xlsm file

Tags: vba, excel, save

I created a userform with code in Excel VBA earlier today. I saved the file as macro enabled .xlsm. I went to go open the file an hour later and get an error message. The message says  "Excel cannot open the file "XYZ.xlsm because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has no been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file". Any advise would be greatly appreciated. I have searched high and low and tried so many different methods but cant seem to get it to work.

PS. I'm running Windows 10, Excel 2016, created in Excel 2016.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what the file looks like in File Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe have a corrupted Excel file.
If you can open other similar files in Excel, then you should maybe take a look at this Microsoft article how to Repair a corrupted workbook:

[Link to the Microsoft article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-a-corrupted-workbook-153a45f4-6cab-44b1-93ca-801ddcd4ea53)

In few steps, when you open your Excel

1. go to File > Open
2. navigate to this file
3. Click the arrow next to the Open button, and then click Open and Repair.